# default route interface name

Tags: command-line, networking, scripts

I want the default interface name. How do I do this without perl?

```
ip route show to default | perl -pe's/^default via [0-9.]+ dev ([0-9a-z]+).*/$1/'
```

Is this working with other distributions also? There are names like ens3p0 or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command:

```
ip route show to default | grep -Eo "dev\s*[[:alnum:]]+" | sed 's/dev\s//g'
```

Information:

- `grep -Eo "dev\s*[[:alnum:]]+"`: Get the device name after the ord "dev".
- `sed 's/dev\s//g'`: Remove the leading space from the previous output.